# Can I cause RSpec to fail if I accidentally use the database?

Tags: ruby, activerecord, rspec

I have one set of tests that I expect to use the database, and another set where I do not want to hit the database. Is there an easy way that I can configure RSpec to fail if I accidentally access the database? Even knowing how to tell if the database was used would give me a starting point.

Comment: Before suggesting anything - have you tried to run your tests with the database shut down? `ActiveRecord` will access your database as soon as you touch one of your model classes.

Comment: I must be missing something... if my database is not running, then my tests that do require the database will fail. Are you suggesting that my tests should turn the database on and off while the tests are running?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [nulldb](https://github.com/nulldb/nulldb). From the README:

```
describe "stuff that shouldn't touch the database" do
  after :each do
    Employee.connection.should_not have_executed(:anything)
  end
  # ...
end
```

You'll need to set up the NullDB adapter for the specific tests where you want to isolate the database. But you should be able to do this while not interfering with the other tests where you want to allow database operations.